# When accessing Odata through tabs or search an error is returned

Tags: search, externalid, lightning-connect, external-lookup

I am getting error when trying to access The record with external ID "/o" is currently unavailable in the external data source. 
Error from Search: (searched on customer 600)

The query is giving this error as a result (the result is api with paramter).
Outside salesforce environment things are working fine (with updated API).

May I know how salesforce query in oData by specify the $filter option.How is SFDC do that in connector.

Also , i have a document but it not fulfilling the req. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000228082&language=en_US

Guide me please